# Missing HttpOnly cookies in Selenium/Docker container, when calling IIS website

Tags: iis, docker, vpn, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

Unsure if this is <s>Selenium</s>, <s>chromedriver</s>, Docker or IIS-specific. I am using Docker for Windows (beta, with Hyper-V) on my PC. On the same PC, I am using IIS to serve a website.

When using the `selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:2.53.0` image to run a test on that website, the Chrome instance in the container does not receive any HttpOnly-cookies (I have used VNC to check). It does get normal cookies though. This means the CSRF token is gone, and trying to POST a form fails.

Works fine if I visit the website on my PC. Both my PC and the container has the domain for the website in their HOSTS-file.

Normal traffic (HTTP GET) works fine from the container, the only difference (thus far) is that it does not get HttpOnly-cookies.

**Edit**: When I opened up for navigating to external sites I do receive HttpOnly-cookies. So this is probably not related to Selenium or the chromedriver.

It might be related to use of VPN on my host PC, which I need for the local IIS website.

Comment: I am also having issues using the Docker Beta for windows on a local iis website and it seems to be related to the VPN not being passed to the docker container but I will need to test it a bit to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out not to be a problem with Docker/Selenium/chromedriver/VPN.

We had a request filter that added the Secure-flag to cookies that are sent with the response, but only to requests that comes from remote machines. The Docker container is in this case seen as a remote machine.

When testing on my local IIS I am doing this over HTTP, which means that secure (HTTPS) cookies are not sent.